# How can I customize a date and time chooser

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker, material-design, customization

I wanna make a custom fragment to choose date ana time like the one on justPark app. Can someone help me with a turo or link to do it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's Calendar API to create your very own implementation with any user interface you like. But making a fully proportionate calendar type view date picker is a lengthy task and would take some time.Since the android's default date picker is flexible enough to adapt your app's theme you may not find custom calendar implementations commonly but sure you can checkout 3rd party libraries.

Here's one for example [caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) 
its a custom calendar implementation in a fragment.

Hope this helps.